# Get all custom product attributes in magento

Tags: magento, attributes, get, product

> Hi i need get all custom attributes of products on frontend to update

, for that i am using the

```
<?php $collection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load("58"); 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($collection1); ?>
```

> but this doesn’t return the custom attribute in arrays
>
> I have some yes.no attributes and some text attributes for products.

Please suggest me how can i achieve this.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rohit Goel ,if you want to get all  attribute value then used below code

```
$collection1->getData();
```